# SQL outer Join 3 tables merging data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I would like to join 3 tables together and have it return the data where the results from one would be null.

tblCustomer is the main table that will always have the required result. It would then be tied to 2 other tables tblEvents and tblPending and should return with the data for either.

Example

```
tblCustomer.CustomerID       tblEvents.EventID      tblPending.PendingID
1                            50                     NULL
1                            51                     NULL
2                            NULL                   30
2                            70                     NULL
2                            NULL                   90
```

I've tried outer joining the tables like so:

```
dbo.tblEvents 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCustomer 
  ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPending 
  ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
```

But it gives me results like this:

```
  CustomerID     EventID      PendingID
  2              70           30
  2              70           90
```

Is there a simple way to make it joins to the Customer table but does not try to join to the additional table. IE there is no relationship between Pending and Event except they are both related to Customer.

Comment: You tagged this as both mysql and sqlserver. Do you really need a solution for both?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've removed the mysql tag. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2013.

Comment: There is no such thing as SQL Server 2013. It is ether 2012 or 2014 which is not out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one of event or pending you may want the union of two joins, e.g.

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblEvents.EventID, null AS tblPending.PendingID FROM dbo.tblCustomer LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
UNION
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerID, null AS tblEvents.EventID, tblPending.PendingID FROM dbo.tblCustomer LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPending ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks. Running 2 select statements and using Union worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a FULL OUTER JOIN, which doesnt exist in mysql, so you have to do your left outer join and union with a right outer join

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPending ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID 
UNION
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPending ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
```

after this, the tables should be combined in the correct order and you can filter out by a field not being null or a specific id

Answer (score 0):

This would get nulls from events and/or pending from sql server

```
select customerid, eventid, pendingid 
from tblcustomer c
left join tblevents e
on c.customerid = e.customerid
left join tblPending p
on c.customerid = p.customerid
```

you can add a where clause to get only value where pending is null by...

```
... where p.pendingid is null
```

Or where events is null

```
... where e.eventsid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbo.tblEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.tblCustomer ON 
dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID  = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID
```

...means that you want to keep everything in tblEvents and only those tblCustomer that are equal. You really want tblCustomer to keep everything.

So the correct SQL would be:

```
dbo.tblEvents RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblCustomer ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblPending ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
```

I personally like to begin with the MAIN table (Customer) and have everything stem from that; it's logical and easier to read.

```
dbo.tblCustomer LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblEvents ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.tblPending ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
```

To select only those with a null from Events or Pending, add the where clause to the end:

```
WHERE dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID Is Null or dbo.tblPending.CustomerID Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbo.tblEvents  
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomer 
  ON dbo.tblEvents.CustomerID = dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblPending 
  ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustomerID = dbo.tblPending.CustomerID
   where (tblEvents.EventID is null) or (tblPending.PendingID is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from selecting wrong table in `FROM` clause. Since you always want to display customer records but only `EVENT` or `PENDING` if they exist than you need to start your query with `CUSTOMER` and include other two with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` meaning that all data from Customer will be retrieved + records that match from each table.

```
SELECT c.CustomerId
       ,e.EventID
       ,p.PendingID
    FROM dbo.tblCustomer AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEvents AS e
        ON c.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPending AS p
        ON c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID
```

Another suggestion is to use `ALIAS`, in my code i have `as c` which lets me refer to `tblCustomer` as `c` instead of specifying the whole table again.